# React Performance Timing on VDOM vs virtual DOM

Tags: reactjs

Looking to calculate VDOM vs DOM below is my code but both of the event click showing the same timing, let me know what am missing out looking out for difference performance timings. ..?

```js
`class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }
  handle = () =>
  {
    this.setState({name:'Sample'});
  }
  
  handleDOM = () =>
  {
   document.getElementById('lblName').innerHTML='Test';
   this.setState({name:'Sample'});
  }render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="V-Dom Click timings" onClick={this.handle}/>
        <br/>
        <label>{this.state.name}</label>

        <input type="button" value="Dom Click timings" onClick= 
      {this.handleDOM}/>
        <br/>
        <label id='lblName'></label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question exactly what you want to test. React's `setState` is asynchronous, so you won't be able to measure what it does by adding a timer around it. Also, in this simple example both will be very fast. If you do have a React performance issue you want to investigate, you can use the profiler extension: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

Comment: Hi, Want to test how fast the react response using setState function compare to normal Javascript DOM manipulation..? can get suitable example where can see the performance improvement ..? My above example shows the same with sample code.;
handle click function : act from setState function but handleDOM : it all touch a DOM and later use setState funciton

Comment: If you have two implementations, one with React and one with plain JS manipulation, you can compare their performance by using browser tools like Chrome DevTools' Performance tab (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) or Lighthouse (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/#devtools)